# Extracting text from the 1st and 4th column of a HTML table row with "grep"

Tags: bash, grep

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in the grep statement? I think I'm just missing an escape character.

```
for i in "${!PORTARR[@]}"; do
  grep \<td\>"${!PORTARR[i]}"\<\/td\> tmp/portlist >> databases/ports.db
done
```

#### *** UPDATE ***

Well unfortunately that's not going to work. Here is ultimately what I am trying to do.

From this string:

```html
<tr><td>4</td><td>TCP</td><td>UDP</td><td>Unassigned</td><td>Official</td></tr>
```

I need to get this:

```
4,Unassigned
```

Comment: What platform?  Linux, Mac, Solaris, Cygwin?  Also please share (in normal text) the pattern you're searching for (rather than just providing the escaped pattern in your grep command).

Comment: Also... What are the contents of the variables in your array?  Please provide more information.

Comment: just port numbers ie 22 or 80

Comment: grep "\<td\>\"${!PORTARR[i]}\"\<\/td\>" no worky

Comment: Ubuntu Linux and the patten to search is <td>22</td>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you meant to write `${PORTARR[i]}` (the `i`th element of `PORTARR`) instead of `${!PORTARR[i]}` (the value of the variable named by the `i`th element of `PORTARR`); so:

```
for i in "${!PORTARR[@]}"; do
  grep \<td\>"${!PORTARR[i]}"\<\/td\> tmp/portlist >> databases/ports.db
done
```

But I'd recommend a few other tweaks as well:

```
for elem in "${PORTARR[@]}"; do
  grep "<td>$elem</td>" tmp/portlist
done > databases/ports.db
```

---

**Update:** For your updated question, I think you're better off using a real programming language, like Perl:

```
perl -we ' my @ports = @ARGV;
           @ARGV = ();
           my %ports = map +($_ => undef), @ports;
           while(<>) {
               my $fields = m/<td>([^<]*)<\/td>/g;
               if(exists $ports{$fields[0]}) {
                   $ports{$fields[0]} = $fields[3];
               }
           }
           foreach my $port (@ports) {
               if(defined $ports{$port}) {
                   print "$port,$ports{$port}\n";
               }
           }
         ' "${PORTARR[@]}" < tmp/portlist > databases/ports.db
```

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Comment: HAHA you are indeed correct sir. IDK how that extra ! got in there. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Well crud, perhaps you could help once more. See update above.